# @ControllerAdvice not triggered on unit testing

Tags: spring-boot, testing, exception, mockito, junit5

I need to test @ControllerAdvice methods which are in service layer. But I faced two issues:

1. ExceptionHandlers not triggered
2. And even if it would be triggered, I find out that don't now how to test it)

@Slf4j
@ControllerAdvice
public class AppExceptionHandler {

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {.class})
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleMyException(MyException ex, WebRequest request) {
ErrorMessage errorMessage = ErrorMessage.builder()
   .message(ex.getMessage())
   .httpStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
   .time(ZonedDateTime.now())
   .build();
return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

}

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyExceptionTest {

   private final AppExceptionHandler handler;
   @Mock private final MyService service;

   @Test
   public void test() throws MyException {
      when(service.create(any()))
          .thenThrow(MyException .class);
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you should write `integration-test` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose, you can write a test for your controller layer with `@WebMvcTest` as this [will create a Spring Test Context](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-mockmvc/) for you that contains all `@ControllerAdvice`.

As your service is throwing this exception, you can mock the service bean with `@MockBean` and use Mockito to instruct your bean to throw the expected exception.

As I don't know how your controller looks like, the following is a basic example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
class PublicControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  private MyService myService;
  
  @Test
  public void testException() throws Exception {
    when(myService.create(any())).thenThrow(new MyException.class);
    
    this.mockMvc
      .perform(get("/public"))
      .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
  }
}
```